# What is the type of a number with underscores separating its digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the type of yes_votes in those codes?
If it is a string, why no ‘’or “” ?
If it is a integer, what is the meaning of ‘_’?

```
yes_votes = 42_572_654
no_votes = 43_132_495
percentage = yes_votes / (yes_votes + no_votes)
'{:-9} YES votes  {:2.2%}'.format(yes_votes, percentage)
```

Comment: Underscores in the middle of a number are ignored in python. It's only there so the number is easier to read. `yes_votes` is an `int`.

Comment: Try [`type(yes_votes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)